# Firestore populated DropdownButton Item is not showing as selected, but snackbar shows otherwise

Tags: flutter, firebase, drop-down-menu, snackbar

I am looking to keep the selected item from a DropdownButton list as the text in that button. Right now, I can click on the item in the dropdown list and I am showing a snackbar notification with the item selected, but it is not updating the actual dropdownbutton's text. What am I missing?

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class InfoScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const InfoScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<InfoScreen> createState() => _InfoScreenState();
}

class _InfoScreenState extends State<InfoScreen> {
  String selectedFaction = '';
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          icon: const Icon(Icons.person_sharp),
        ),
        elevation: 5,
        centerTitle: true,
        titleSpacing: 0,
        title: const Text('Info Screen'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: const Icon(Icons.settings),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collection("factions")
                    .snapshots(),
                builder: (BuildContext context,
                    AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    final factionDatabaseSnapshot = snapshot.data!.docs;
                    factionDatabaseSnapshot.sort(
                      ((a, b) {
                        return a['name']
                            .toLowerCase()
                            .compareTo(b['name'].toLowerCase());
                      }),
                    );
                    return DropdownButton(
                      onChanged: (snap) {
                        setState(() {
                          selectedFaction = snap.toString();
                        });
                        final snackbarFaction = SnackBar(
                          content: Text('Faction Selected: $selectedFaction'),
                        );
                        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                            .showSnackBar(snackbarFaction);
                      },
                      items: factionDatabaseSnapshot
                          .map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                          value: document['name'],
                          child: Text(document['name']),
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                      isExpanded: false,
                      isDense: false,
                      hint: const Text('Select a faction'),
                    );
                  } else {
                    return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                  }
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[Screenshot of what I am seeing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjTg3.png)

I'd also like to save this item into Firestore on a 'submit' button, but I haven't gotten that far yet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Update: [Error I am receiving after adding the code from the answer selected below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhnKT.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is fine you just need to add value property inside dropdown -

```
return DropdownButton(
value: selectedFaction,
                  onChanged: (snap) {
                    setState(() {
                      selectedFaction = snap.toString();
                    });
                    final snackbarFaction = SnackBar(
                      content: Text('Faction Selected: $selectedFaction'),
                    );
                    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                        .showSnackBar(snackbarFaction);
                  },
```